# .Net mvc EF codefirst how to hanle concurrent update requests to database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, model-view-controller, concurrency, entity-framework-5

I've got a table in database:

```
USERID   MONEY
______________
  1       500
```

The money value could be changed only by logged in user that owns account. I've got a function like:

```
bool buy(int moneyToSpend)
{
    var moneyRow = db.UserMoney.Find(loggedinUserID);
    if(moneyRow.MONEY < moneyToSpend)
        return false;
    //code for placing order
    moneyRow.MONEY -= moneyToSpend;
    return true;
}
```

I know that mvc sessions are always synchronous, so there will never be 2 symulateous calls to this function in one user session. But what if user logs in to the site 2 times from different browsers? Will it be still single threaded session or I can get 2 concurrent requests to this function?
And if there will be concurrency then how should I handle it with EF? Normally in ADO I would use MSSQL's "BEGIN WORK" for this type of situation, but I have no idea on how to make it with EF.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `RowVersion` to handle concurrent requests.

Good reference here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
// in UserMoney.cs
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

// in model builder
modelBuilder.Entity<UserMoney>().Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken();

// The update logic
public bool Buy(int moneyToSpend, byte[] rowVersion)
{
    try
    {
        var moneyRow = db.UserMoney.Find(loggedinUserID);
        if(moneyRow.MONEY < moneyToSpend)
        {            
            return false;
        }

        //code for placing order
        moneyRow.MONEY -= moneyToSpend;
        return true;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
        var submittedUserMoney = (UserMoney) entry.Entity;
        var databaseValue = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

        if (databaseValue == null)
        {
            // this entry is no longer existed in db
        }
        else
        {
            // this entry is existed and have newer version in db
            var userMoneyInDb = (UserMoney) databaseValue.ToObject();
        }
    }
    catch (RetryLimitExceededException)
    {
        // probably put some logs here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it would be a major problem for you since the idea is that MSSQL as far as i know will not allow asyncroneus data commits to the same user from the same thread it has to finish one process before moving to the next one but  you can try something like this

```
using (var db = new YourContext()) 
{ 
    var moneyRow = db.UserMoney.Find(loggedinUserID);
    moneyRow.MONEY -= moneyToSpend; 

    bool saveFailed; 
    do 
    { 
        saveFailed = false; 
        try 
        { 
            db.SaveChanges(); 
        } 
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) 
        { 
            saveFailed = true; 

            // Update original values from the database 
            var entry = ex.Entries.Single(); 
            entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(entry.GetDatabaseValues()); 
        } 

    } while (saveFailed); 
}
```

More can be found here [Optimistic Concurrency Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx)